# generate unique Long for unique String seed

Tags: java, string, algorithm, long-integer

I need to generate a unique `Long` of length of 10 or more digits from String seed that can be of any length. In normal circumstances it would be not possible to do since there are more `String` permutations than `Long` can store, however i know that system will not generate more `Strings` than i can store in `Long`, how can i generate unique `Long` for each `String` in such circumstances?

I can not use dynamic perfect hashing since is too time consuming and i can not use minimal perfect hash function since i dont want generated numbers to seqentional.

EDIT: i can not store any information about already processed Strings, including amount of them

Comment: Hm... If that where be possible, would we still use a map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a counter like this

```
final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
final Map<String, Long> idMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public long idFor(String s) {
    return idMap.computeIfAbsent(s, isMap::incrementAndGet);
}
```

This will return a unique id for each String.

Comment: this would be a good solution but i can not store any information about already processed Strings, including amount of processed strings (will add this rule to post)

Comment: @AkkaJaworek without storing any information, you need a hashing strategy which will be random rather than unique.

Comment: @AkkaJaworek or you need a means of parsing the String to a unique number. e.g, say the String contains a unique number you can parse.

Comment: if i know that: 1. each string is unique. 2. amount of strings is lesser than ``MAX_INT`` would there still be posibility that using ``hashCode()`` will generate two identical integers? if not then i could use them as seed for random float generator

Comment: @AkkaJaworek well "bb" and "cC" have the same hashCode. There is hundreds of examples just for 2 characters.  Using a random seed will mean that different Strings collide but make them no less likely.

Comment: I believe this is the only way, to create a unique long id from a string.

Comment: ok, then i guess i will have to trust randomness since i know that there will be less than 1*10^10 Strings and there is 1*10^-10 chance of generating exactly same float as already existing one in worst case scenario, and i can not afford any information storing

Comment: @PeterLawrey Well this doesn't answer the question at all... The question was about String being "seed", here it's not a seed at all, it's just element of the sequence. This is contrary to the: "I can not store any information about already processed Strings".  + is the AtomicLong counter even used in the code?

Comment: @AkkaJaworek unfortunately the birthday strategy means you have good chance of a duplicate around the square root of possible values ie about 10^5. This is because each new random number has to be different to all the previous values and the sum. Of these chances reaches around 50% surprisingly quickly.

Comment: @PiotrR and yet it's the best solution closest to the requirement. If you know a better one please provide an answer. The seed makes no difference as explained which is why it is not included.